# Paramiko module not found

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, ssh, paramiko

When I try to `import paramiko`, when I try to run [rforward.py](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/blob/master/demos/rforward.py) from the [paramiko demo files](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/tree/master/demos), it shows error :

```
./rforward.py
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./rforward.py", line 36, in <module>
    import paramiko
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

And when I try to install paramiko via pip,

```
pip install paramiko
```

It shows :

```
Requirement already satisfied: paramiko in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.6.0)
```

My python version is **2.7.18**. I had installed `paramiko` for a different `python3` program using `pip3 install paramiko`
Will completely removing it and re-installing it with `pip` instead of `pip3` help? Will this loose the module from `python3`
**EDIT :**

```
python --version
Python 2.7.18
```

```
find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -iname "*paramiko*"

/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko
/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/paramiko-2.6.0.egg-info
```

Any suggestions please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is this an issue between installing as user, but running your `rforward.py` as administrator? If that's the case, run `pip install paramiko` as administrator as well - otherwise the library ends up in your user folder and "not accessible" by administrator.

Comment: What is `which python` resulting in?

Comment: @albert /usr/bin/python

Comment: @Torxed is installed as admin

Comment: `python --version` and `find /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages -iname "*paramiko*"`. Add the results in your question not in the comment section.

Comment: Ah wait, you have to do `pip2 install paramiko`, if you're running Python3 as the standard python. Are you running Arch LInux for instance, the default pip and python will be 3, but if you're running python2 enforced you'll have to force-use the Python2 version of PIP as well.

Comment: It is not working, ```bash: pip2: command not found```

Comment: Lets start from the beginning, what operating system are you running (specifics are important)

Comment: @Torxed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: Your default version of Python (and pip) should there for be `python2` and `pip` (implying pip2). What does `pip --version` say?

Comment: ```pip 20.0.2 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.8)```

Comment: If you are only just learning the basics, you should probably ignore Python 2, and spend your time on the currently recommended and supported version of the language, which is Python 3.

Comment: @tripleee Na, I had a piece of code which was in python2. It was a pain in the ass to convert it into python3. So I thought to run it in the same. Any way, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This thread helped my particular case, hope it does help you too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65869296/installing-pip-is-not-working-in-python-3-6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with `pip`. The `pip` and `pip3` I had installed in the same path, `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`. I installed a pip specifically for python 2.7. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62771974/pip-for-python2-while-python3-pip-exists). Now `pip` installs for python and `pip3` for python3.