# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tesseract' "

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I install 'tesseract' in anaconda cloud but when I tried to use the module it shows the message  " ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tesseract' "

Comment: Did you import ?

Comment: How did you install tesseract ?

Comment: yes I do, install tesseract by using conda install -c conda-forge pytesseract
 command

Comment: import pytesseract
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-86e8598aa017>", line 1, in <module>
    import pytesseract

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytesseract'
This is the error I'm getting

Comment: Are you using the correct Python installation for the notebook?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Paramiko module not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62258110/paramiko-module-not-found)